# Minimum Heap - Add k to all left keys and heapify efficiently

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, data-structures, heaps

I've been trying to solve this problem:

> Given a minimum heap $H$, which contains $n$ elements, where each of its keys contain natural numbers, as well as $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
>
> Add the value $k$ to each of the keys on the left from the root, (Which means to add to each element in the heap which has an index of the form $i = 2^j$.
>
> Determine the complexity of the algorithm by declaring a function $f(n)$ so that the complexity of the algorithm would be $\Theta(f(n))$

My intuition for such a process is to perform a `Min-Heapify` for the root, but it seems to me that this might not be the most efficient way to tackle this problem, as the only elements that have been changed are the left most route.

I'd appreciate any insight on the matter,
Thank you.

Comment: I would just like to clarify, you will add $k$ then fix the heap? I assume you would add $k$ to each element with index $2^i$ in one pass before fixing the heap, is that right?

Comment: @Russel, thanks for your answer. To answer your question, your assumption is correct. That is exactly what is going on. Since working on this problem, I realized that I can basically run MinHeapify on each node starting from the node $2^j$ where $j$ equals to the floored value of $log{(n)}$.
The overall complexity should be $log^2{(n)}$,  and therefore, the function $f(n) = log^2{(n)}$ can be proven for $\Theta(f(n))$